# How do I turn embed into a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to turn source of [this website](https://api.freckle.com/2/ela/adaptive-skills/system-domains/RI.4/summary?x-echo=2a923c1c-a07b-47a9-9841-5821b1aa4e28%20Request%20Headers) into a variable or string using only JavaScript.

I have tried using document.innerHTML, but the source doesn’t have any HTML at all, it’s just 1 line of text. I need to turn that line of text into a variable in only JavaScript. I am a beginner, so just be simple, thank you!

Comment: The URL you gave is inaccessible if you're not a student.  It doesn't matter: you need to be clearer about the problem.  Update your post with an [MCVE] if possible.  At a minimum, please 1) Copy/paste what you see, 2) Better describe what you *expect* to see, 3) Better explain what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Javascript Fetch API.

```
const yourVariable = fetch('https://api.freckle.com/2/ela/adaptive-skills/system-domains/RI.4/summary?x-echo=2a923c1c-a07b-47a9-9841-5821b1aa4e28%20Request%20Headers')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

I've included the JSON conversion step because it looks like the API you're hitting gives a JSON response. If this is not the case, simply omit the `.then(res => res.json())` line.

Comment: did you taste the solution?

Comment: @someuser Apart from the fact that the asker-provided API URL doesn't have the correct credentials to return anything other than a permissions error, yes this is tested and works for the provided URL.